# RestSharp returning an empty array to json deserialize

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net, restsharp

I am having an issue when I rune a RestSharp request on my api.  The content response that I am getting is an empty array.  Any idea as to why this would by empty when I try and send the values to my model? (It seemed to work fine when I ran a get user, I think it may have to do with using an IEnumerable)

Here is my RestSharp request:

```
var request = new RestRequest("/problems/", Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("id-header", id);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

var response = client.Execute(request) as RestResponse;

List<MyModel> d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyModel>>(response.Content);

return View(d);
```

Here is my method in my API:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(ProblemModel))]
public IQueryable<ProblemModel> GetProblems()
{
    var problems = User.Companies
                       .SelectMany(c => c.Projects)
                       .SelectMany(p => p.Problems)
                       .AsQueryable<Problem>()
                       .Select(factory.AsProblemModel);

    return problems;
}
```

And My Model the RestSharp is using:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> AssignedToId { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Make sure that you tag your questions correctly. You're not just using RestSharp, you're also using JSON.Net.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about restSharp, but it would look more natural for GetDefects()  to return an IEnumerable  instead of an IQueryable